# How can I make the fonts in Firefox web browser looks like in chromium based browsers? [Windows 10]

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, fonts

I don't know why the font looks soo rough and overshooted. Take a look:

Google Chrome printscreen of Apple II series' Wikipédia page
[image]

Mozilla Firefox printscreen of Apple II series' Wikipédia page
[image]

Google Chrome printscreen of font rendering test*
[image]

Mozilla Firefox printscreen of font rendering test*
[image]

Printscreen of my Firefox's font settings
[image]

These settings are the same that I use in *Google Chrome* and *Microsoft Edge*.

Have any settings that I should change to make the fonts better looking? Or maybe, some Windows' setting is affecting Firefox's font rendering?

This is one of my biggest complaints about Firefox and that keeps pushing me away from it.

*[*Font rendering test website*](https://tests.caniuse.com/?feat=css-font-rendering-controls)

---

System info:

- Windows 10 Pro x64 19041;
- Firefox Browser x64 88.0.1;
- Google Chrome x64 90.0.4430.212.

Comment: Go to `about:config`, toggle `gfx.text.disable-aa` then restart the browser. Any better?

Comment: A put `true` and got worse :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Around version 95 Firefox improved the font rendering and things looks crispy as expected. I'm using Firefox's default font settings.

Answer (score 2):

Try these settings below in `about:config`:

| Property name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.enhanced_contrast | 100 |
| gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.pixel_structure | 5 |
| gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.rendering_mode | 5 |

Not quite like in Chrome but better than default settings

For reference: [image linked in original answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZqO0.jpg)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1087435)

Comment: Indeed smooths out the font rendering. But depending on the text (e.g., PDFs), the glyphs will be "washed", so I kept the default values.

Comment: Some update, now I use these settings:
gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.cleartype_level 400 
gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.enhanced_contrast 12 
gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.pixel_structure 0 
gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.rendering_mode 3

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue and found that changing in

about:config

```
gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.enhanced_contrast
```

to 0

gives exactly the same font as in Chrome